# The best way to schedule a event

Tags: php, mysql, cron, scheduled-tasks

is there any other option other than cron to schedule the running of a php backup script at a certain time?. I know you can use php itself to schedule things, but it will only fire if the site is getting traffic.
Are there any other options ?.
Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about a database backup, then MySQL 5.1 and above has [CREATE EVENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) which can be used to trigger events (such as stored procedures that can dump table structure/data to file) at regular intervals or set times

Comment: Does this need traffic to the site to trigger?

Comment: No traffic to the site is needed at all.... it's purely triggered by time, not activity

Answer (score 1):

Well, cron jobs is a solution. But not necessary in most cases.

If your script is doing something off the site (like sending an email or something), it must be a cron-job.

But...

I made a textbased rpg-game once where several actions were stored in the database waiting to get triggered at a specified time. I found out that it did not make any difference if the script fired at the time it should, or when the first person visiting the page after the time is beyond the timestamp. You could do these events before displaying the content of the page. (I used a file called monitor, to keep it simple).

Would you like to say more about your "event"?

Comment: The event is just the calling of the backup script, I think I will use cron, it was just that the backup schedule needs to be changed via php, I know this can be done with cron and php, I just wondered if there was an easier way as I have not used php to alter cron scripts before, only set them up in my hosting control panel. The only other way I can think is if I get cron to run the script every 15 mins and when the time = timeset run the function.

Comment: Ah, backups will require a cronjob. There are plenty of guides (it's not difficult).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you feel like writing a daemon/service/etc., cron would be your best bet. If you need a job ran more often than minutely, use a lockfile solution and a looping script.

Answer (score 0):

Well not really, Crons are your best bet.

Other than that call a script, and if certain parameters are met such as time elapsed then run the script.